# Create a Stephan Few bullet chart with a benchmark element

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
library(ggplot2)
cbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00")

sentiment <- c(0.2, 0.05)
names <- c("test1", "test2")
df <- data.frame(sentiment, names)
```

And I use this to create the following plot

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(names, sentiment, fill = names))
pp <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour="black") + coord_flip() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral")
```

This works fine. However I would like to include a benchmark in it. A little like a stephen few bullet chart. So in both charts I want to include a smaller blacker bar that serves a benchmark. Any thoughts on how I can do that?

Comment: Googling "bullet chart r" would give you several options for this, including hrbrmstr's code for making a bullet chart using ggplot [here](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/Rbulletgraph/blob/master/bulletgraph.R), a [plotly solution](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/Rbulletgraph/blob/master/bulletgraph.R), and others